# Running Nestjs version 9 with Graphql and apollo server v4 gives Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-core'

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I am trying to build a nestjs graphql with federation Schema with schema first approach monorepo of two microservices AUTH and LEDGER and a GATEWAY the AUTH microservice appModule.ts looks like this:

```
import { AuthModule } from './../auth/auth.module';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { join } from 'path';
import { ApolloFederationDriver, ApolloFederationDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';

@Module({
  imports: [
 
        GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloFederationDriverConfig>({
          driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
          autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
          context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
          useGlobalPrefix: true,
      }),
    AuthModule
   ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

However I keep getting  Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-core'. Now I am not using apollo-server-core directly I am using apollo/server v4 and V10 of nest/graphql and nest/apollo. I also understand that nestjs v9 may not be updated to apollo/server v4. can anyone shed some light on this?...what is causing this error? is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, nestjs is not compatible with v4. You can check this: https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/2445